# Understanding the output from svn export

Tags: svn, svn-export

Working on some tweaks for a build script, I noticed that the output from **`svn export`** has an 'A' in column 1 for each file exported.

```
A    C:\build\file1
A    C:\build\file2
A    C:\build\file3
```

The subversion book describes the meaning of the various columns for `svnlook changes` and `svn status`, but I'm not having much luck finding the meaning behind this one.

What does the 'A' in column 1 mean?  Are there any other values displayed there?  Any other columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A" means add.  For import, that's all you'll see.  For other operations, there's other possibilities.  See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html.

Comment: For import, it actually says "Adding".  In my case, it's an export operation.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive it means "added".

The TortiseSVN export output pane uses this terminology.

Answer (score 0):

It means "added".

I've documented the `svn log` export data structure on the [Subversion](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/panbi/index.php?title=Subversion) page of a [BI tool](http://www.PanBI.org) I'm developing. Furthermore, there's a short [screencast](http://panbi.sourceforge.net/systems/subversion/olap.html) providing a rich visualization of the data available in the svn log.